# Two は acting as contrastive terms but not verb (apparently)

Tags: particle-は, ellipsis

I'm trying to translate or at least understand the meaning of this sentence

> 人を知ってゆくのも同じように、あの人はうちのお父さんの銀行の人、この人はお母さんの親類の人という風に、やはり自分が中心になって考えられている。

it seems there are two men (あの人,この人) used in a contrastive fashion (apparently), father and mother's relative playing an identical key role. I am wondering if 考えられている is the same verb for both two "subjects". The speaker is この人, referring to a kid (自分).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The following sentence is それが、大人になると、多かれ少なかれ、地動説のような考え方になってくる。Which sounds as "That will be, more or less, your reasoning scheme in a heliocentric fashion once you become adult".

Answer (score 1):

The あの人はうちのお父さんの銀行の人 and この人はお母さんの親類の人 are two clauses serving as examples of the main point of the sentence that when we think about other people we think of them in terms of relationships to ourselves, with ourselves at the centre.